# whenever i am saving datagridview it saves all the records , even if they are in SQL table. how can I prevent this?

Tags: c#, datagridview

whenever i am saving data of gridview it saves all the data not that rows which are inserted

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.[Ledger_" + tbpg.Text + "] VALUES(@Sno, @Date, @Particulars, @Credit, @Debit, @Balance)";
                query += "DELETE FROM dbo.[Ledger_"+tbpg.Text+"] WHERE Date IS NULL;";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells["Sno"].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = row.Cells["Date"].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Particulars", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells["Particulars"].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Credit", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  row.Cells["Credit"].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Debit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells["Debit"].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Balance", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells["Balance"].Value ?? (object)DBNull.Value;




                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: it is saving all the record means what?

Comment: means : like I edit some rows , so when I click save button it saves all the rows to the table which were already present in the table .

Answer (score 0):

```
//namespaces   
 public partial class Database_Manager : Form
{
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    SqlCommandBuilder scb;
    DataTable dt;
    public Database_Manager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Database_Manager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labeltitle.Text = "Select the table you want to edit.";
    }

    private void dbupdate()
    {
        try {
            scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            sda.Update(dt);
            MessageBox.Show("Update Successful!");
        }
        catch(Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
        }
        }

    private void buttonupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbupdate();
    }
```

The code above could do the trick.Your code inserts record from the datagridview and since you have not explicitly defined which row should be considered it may insert all the datagridview rows.
   The code ihave provided finds updates on existing rows  and also inserts new rows